# input element disappears in IE(10) on backspace

Tags: jquery, asp.net, textbox, html-rendering

I have an `ASP.NET` page that loads a bunch of data from the db into a `ListView` with a `LayoutTemplate` and `ItemTemplate`. When the user hovers over a row, the last column switches its content for a textbox containing the same value, making it editable. This works in Chrome and now I almost got it to work in `IE10` as well.

What issue remains, is that **when backspacing in the textbox, the first keystroke seems to remove the textbox itself but leaves the content and a second keystroke renders both the textbox and the content invisible**. Clicking inside the textbox renders it visible again and so does moving the mouse cursor outside the textbox area.

I was unable to make a Snaggit of this, I tried.

Sadly, the [**jsfiddle here**](http://jsfiddle.net/wimombelets/sJGHD/) does **NOT** reproduce the issue in `IE10` so, risking the old *wall of text*, I'm including the entire `ASP.NET Page` in the hopes that someone else can reproduce this and figure out what I have not been able to in two days. Don't worry, it's not huge. I've tested this code on another machine (using the same version of `IE10` as well) and the issue is identical.

As usual: any insights into the why and how of this problem are appreciated.

```
<%@ Page Title="EditInvoiceNumberFormat" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/myApplication.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="EditInvoiceNumberFormat.aspx.cs" Inherits="myApplication.EditInvoiceNumberFormat" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"></asp:ScriptManager>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').width($('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').closest('td').width() - 5);

        $('tr[id*="itemRow"]').mouseenter(function () {
            $clickedRow = $(this);
            var invNr = $clickedRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text();

            //if the label/span is still visible
            if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').is(':hidden')) {
                //switch to edit mode
                $clickedRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').hide();
                $clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').show();

                //copy over the value and focus the cursor
                $clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').val(invNr).focus();

                //if the value changes
                $clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').on('input propertychange', function () {
                    //if the button was already visible, leave it that way
                    if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').is(':hidden')) {
                        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').show();
                        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').show();
                    }

                    //but if it changes back to what it was within the same 'mouseenter' moment
                    if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').val() == $clickedRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text()) {
                        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').hide();
                        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').hide();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        $('tr[id*="itemRow"]').mouseleave(function () {
            $rowLosingFocus = $(this);

            //if the save button isn't visible
            if ($rowLosingFocus.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').is(':hidden')) {
                $rowLosingFocus.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text($rowLosingFocus.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').val()).show();
                $rowLosingFocus.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').hide();
            }
        });

        //prevent page postback on button click
        $('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //update the value to the db
            UpdateInvoiceNrFormat($(this));
        });

        //prevent postback on enter
        $('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').on('keydown', function (e) {
            if (e.keyCode == 13) { //if 'enter' key
                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
            else return true;
        });

        //prevent backspace to navigate back
        var rx = /INPUT|SELECT|TEXTAREA/i;

        $(document).bind("keydown keypress", function (e) {
            if (e.which == 8) { // 8 == backspace
                if (!rx.test(e.target.tagName) || e.target.disabled || e.target.readOnly) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
    });

    function UpdateInvoiceNrFormat(leButton) {
        $buttonClicked = $(leButton);
        //$buttonClicked.focus();
        $closestRow = $buttonClicked.closest('tr');

        $saveResultMsg = $closestRow.find('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]');

        var invNrFormat = $closestRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').val(),
            companyName = $closestRow.find('span[id$="lblCompanyName"]').text(),
            invoiceType = $closestRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceType"]').text();

        //page method that actually updates the value to the db
        PageMethods.UpdateInvoiceNumberFormat(companyName, invoiceType, invNrFormat, onSuccess, onError);

        function onSuccess(result) {
            $buttonClicked.hide();
            $closestRow.find('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]').text(result).show().fadeOut(1500, function () {
                $(this).hide();
                $(this).closest('td').hide();
            });
        }
        function onError(result) {
            $buttonClicked.hide();
            $closestRow.find('span[id$="SaveResultMsg"]').text('Error:' + result).show();
        }
    }
</script>
    <asp:ListView ID="InvoiceNumberFormatList" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <div runat="server" class="AltRow">
                <p>Select a row to edit the invoice number format.</p>
                <table id="InvoiceNumberFormatTable" runat="server">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Company Name</th>
                        <th>Invoice Type</th>
                        <th>Invoice Number Format</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server"></tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr id="itemRow" runat="server">
                <td style="padding:6px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblCompanyName" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("CompanyName") %>' />
                </td>
                <td style="padding:6px">
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceType" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InvoiceType") %>' />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblInvoiceNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("InvoiceNumber") %>' />
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxInvoiceNumber" runat="server" style="display:none"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
                <td id="SaveOption" style="display:none">
                    <asp:Button ID="btnSaveInvNrFormat" runat="server" Text="Save" />
                    <span id="SaveResultMsg"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>

    <div id="EditWindow" title="Edit Invoice Number Format">

    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Too much code, non-generated HTML code, it's hard to debug...

Comment: yeah, kinda my point too, @NOX. Hence the question ;-)

Comment: You can do View Source in the page and post only the HTML, or even better use that HTML to try and reproduce in the fiddle.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I took out the table HTML from the source and used that in the fiddle. What other HTML do you mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

changing

```
//if the value changes
$clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').on('input propertychange', function () {
    //if the button was already visible, leave it that way
    if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').is(':hidden')) {
        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').show();
        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').show();
    }

    //but if it changes back to what it was within the same 'mouseenter' moment
    if ($clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').val() == $clickedRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text()) {
        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').hide();
        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').hide();
    }
});
```

into

```
//if the value changes
$clickedRow.find('input[id$="txtBoxInvoiceNumber"]').on('input propertychange', function () {
    //but if it changes back to what it was within the same 'mouseenter' moment
    if ($(this).val() == $clickedRow.find('span[id$="lblInvoiceNumber"]').text()) {
        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').hide();
        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').hide();
    } else {
        $clickedRow.find('td[id$="SaveOption"]').show();
        $clickedRow.find('input[id$="btnSaveInvNrFormat"]').show();
    }
});
```

resolved the issue.